# Can we use the search functionality on the website using selenium web browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am working on the web scraping project in which I want to search the specific element by entering a keyword in the search box of the website using Selenium web driver in Python.

e.g. This is the website: www.auchan.fr 
And I want to search for this  EAN "4020628743819" number.

I have tried the following code but its not working:

```
text_area = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/form/input')
text_area.send_keys('4020628743819')
submit_button = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".search-submit[type='submit']").submit()
```

Answer (score 1):

The xpath `//*[@id="search"]/form/input` matches two elements. The search bar is the second, but `find_element_by_xpath` return the first one. You can distinguish between the by the `clone` class added to ancestor element of the first result and look for element that doesn't have this class

```
text_area = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//header[not(contains(@class, "clone"))]//div[@id="search"]//input')
```

Comment: Now, ```submit_button = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".search-submit[type='submit']").submit()``` this line giving me an error as: **'list' object has no attribute 'submit'**

Comment: @PujaNeve `find_elements` return list, use `find_element`